# IPN doesn't seem to work the way it should based on PayPal's docs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We have created a small app to help users manage certain PayPal orders, but the IPN doesn't seem to work as expected. I found this at the note at the bottom of the following URL:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

```
"Even though you have not enabled receiving IPN messages in your Profile or
you have reset your preference by turning off IPN messages, PayPal still    
sends IPN messages to the notification URL you specify for a specific
payment."
```

Based on this we instructed our beta testers not to worry about enabling IPN in their account, since we specify the notification URL for the user's transaction via the notify_url field in the button code. But then no IPN is sent.

Next we instructed our beta testers to enable IPN, and since doing so requires you to enter a notification URL and users don't want transaction data for EVERY transaction posted to our system, and we don't want that either, we instructed them to enter a "fake" URL and disable sending messages to that URL in their account. Based on the note at the link above we figured this should work too, but it doesn't. No IPN is sent, although you can now see the message in the IPN history.

So I'm a little stumped here. The way I see it, we only have 2 options, and neither seems ideal ...

1. Instruct our users to enable IPN and hard-code our IPN notification URL into their profile settings. This means if they're already using IPN for something else they can't do this, and even if they can it means that data for EVERY transaction they do will hit our system and neither the user nor we want that.
2. Instruct our users to enter a "bogus" notification URL in their account, and leave messages to that URL enabled, since we'll override this with our own notify_url setting. This would work, however it will cause PayPal to attempt to send messages to an invalid notification URL for any transactions NOT processed through our system. I assume PayPal doesn't want this, and it could possibly lead to the user losing IPN access in the future due to constant IPN errors, etc.

Anyone have any ideas for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In experience, as you're finding, you do need IPN enabled in order for the IPNs to be sent, but then if you specify notify_url it will override the URL in the profile.

Instead of setting up a bogus URL, though, you could put any actual script there.  Just make it a script that does absolutely nothing.  That way IPNs that get sent here will "do nothing" other than send a 200 OK back to PayPal's server showing that the IPN was received successfully.

If they're already using their own IPN solution and the data needs to go through both then you'll have to setup an IPN forwarder.  You can daisy-chain IPN URLs to that a bunch of them get hit with the same data if you need to.

Personally, I like to have some sort of a catch-all IPN setup in my profile that saves any IPNs it gets to my database for logging purposes.  Then, again, the notify URL can be used to override this if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We can certainly do this, but since merchants only use our system to manage and process SOME of their transactions, a lot of them don't want PayPal's system sending transaction details to our system for the rest of their transactions not processed by our system. It just seems like there has to be a better way...

Comment: What I was saying was that they can setup their own "default" IPN on their own web host.  It could do absolutely nothing, but a success response will go back to PayPal.  Then from your app you would use notify to override that, and only those IPNs would go to your server.

Comment: Yes we could do that but many of our users don't even have their own websites, which is one of the reasons they use our system to process these orders. But thanks for the input, that is certainly an option for people who have their own website and don't want us to receive all of the transaction details for orders not processed through our system.